# Ionic 2 platform add android error

Tags: android, cordova, ionic2

Im trying to build an android app with ionic 2. When I try to run `ionic platform add android` I get this error: `Failed to find 'ANDROID_HOME' environment variable. Try setting setting it manually. Failed to find 'android' command in your 'PATH'`.

Im using linux mint and already set the environment variables like this:

```
export ANDROID_HOME=/home/mauro/Android/Sdk
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

When I type `android` in the console, the sdk manager gets started.

My ionic version is: 2.1.7
and cordova: 6.4.0

Hope anybody can help me with this issue.

Comment: after a search o read this https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=207639 try to put in the bashrc  this `export ANDROID_HOME="/home/tacomeat/android-sdks"` with "

Comment: error still occurs

Answer (score 1):

Instruction 1: 
After adding your ANDROID_HOME, make sure you do the below:

1. Restart your System or run source ~/.bash_profile
2. Remove Android platform from your project ionic cordova platform rm android or ionic platform rm android
3. Add Android platform ionic cordova platform add android
4. Then ionic cordova run android or ionic run android

Instruction 2: 
To set your ANDROID_HOME and JAVA_HOME, follow the below steps:

1. Run command open ~/.bash_profile
2. Paste the below in the file that opens on your Text editor

export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/Cellar/android-sdk/24.4.1_1
export PATH=${PATH}:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools

3. Save  -  "Command S" or "Ctrl S"
4. Then Follow the "Instruction 1:" above

Hope this helps.....

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue. It seems to be an issue of the combination of cordova, the installed Android SDK version and the profile settings.

This is what worked for me on ubuntu 16.10:

- get an older cordova that is known to work:

  npm install -g cordova@4.2
  (I was on 6.4.0 and 5.0.0)
- in .profile:

  PATH="~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools:~/Android/Sdk/tools:$PATH"
  export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android/Sdk
  (Seems you are good there)

I needed the latter to stop the complaining about it even while android was in my path and it also gave me meaningfull errors, which was that API 22 was missing.

Load the profile in current bash:

```
source ~/.profile
```

Type `android` and install SDK 22.
Exit when done and type

```
ionic build android
```

and it should work.